# Scaling creates new faces?

Tags: transforms, edges, loop

I'm very new to Blender and I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7m3QkwRcGE&t=217s) tutorial on youtube but facing an issue with scaling:

In the video scaling an edge loop has this effect on the object:
[image]

Whereas when I do it seems to just add more faces/ another loop instead of moving and affecting the surrounding object:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone help?

Thanks

Edit: animated gif of behavior on my side:
[image]

Comment: hello, it's not clear what's happening, could you also show an animated gif of your own screen?

Comment: @moonboots Just added a gif, thanks

Comment: it looks like you have 2 overlapping edge loops, maybe select all and press M > Merge by Distance to remove all overlapping vertices, then try to scale again